# Using stringdist in R

Tags: r, stringdist

Lets say I have the following words:

```
word1 = 'john lennon'
word2 = 'john lenon'
word3 = 'lennon john'
```

Its almost clear that these 3 words are reffering to the same person. Having the following code:

```
library(stringdist)
>stringdist('john lennon','john lenon',method = 'jw')
[1] 0.06363636
>stringdist('john lennon','lennon john',method = 'qgram')
[1] 0
>stringdist('john lennon','lennon john',method = 'jw')
[1] 0.33
>stringdist('john lennon','john lenon',method = 'qgram')
[1] 1
```

Its clear that in this example that `qgram` works better. But thats only that case. My question is how can I combine these two methods?

`jw` gives better results but cant 'catch' the reversed words ( in my case name-surname with surname-name). Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an idea which computationally seems to be costly, but at least it gives quite nice results.

```
word1 = 'john lennon'
word2 = 'john lenon'
word3 = 'lennon john'
```

Firstly remove spaces:

```
word1b = gsub(' ','',word1)
word2b = gsub(' ','',word2)
word3b = gsub(' ','',word3)
```

Order them alphabetically:

```
word1c = paste(sort(unlist(strsplit(word1b, ""))), collapse = "")
word2c = paste(sort(unlist(strsplit(word2b, ""))), collapse = "")
word3c = paste(sort(unlist(strsplit(word3b, ""))), collapse = "")
```

And finally use `jw` method:

```
stringdist(word1c,word2c,method = 'jw')
[1] 0.03333333
stringdist(word1c,word3c,method = 'jw')
[1] 0
stringdist(word2c,word3c,method = 'jw')
[1] 0.03333333
```

Satisfactory results.
Drawback: could have non wanted results in small length words.

Comment: If you're comparing character counts, it is easier to use stringdist(word1,word2,method="qgram",q=1), which is not as costly.

Answer (score 1):

you could integrate an "if" statement which will run the `jw` method if and only if the `qgram` is not equal to 0. i.e.
`if(stringdist(('john lennon','john lenon',method = 'qgram')!=0){stringdist('john lennon','john lenon',method = 'jw')}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But still doesnt take all the cases. For example: `stringdist('john lennon','lenon john',method = 'qgram')` which is not zero using qgram and has high distance when using `jw`.

Comment: So to be clear, what answer would you want for the case: `stringdist('john lennon','lenon john')`?

Comment: Considering that `stringdist('john lennon','john lenon',method = 'jw')` gives `0.06`, a value of `0.1` for `stringdist('john lennon','lenon john')` would be fair.